# Merge Tags: redirect and redirects

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I think these 2 should be merged

'redirect' and 'redirects'

They are both on, hmm, redirects

Maybe a synonym is in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've merged them. Also, [redirects](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/redirects) is a synonym of [redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/redirect) now.